# Summarize count of multi table in single SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, summarization

I have three table with below details:

Table 1: worklog

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| worklogid | technician | description |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 1         | john       | some text   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 2         | jack       | some text   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 3         | john       | some text   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
| 4         | jenifer    | some text   |
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

Table 2: task

```
+--------+-------+-------------+
| taskid | owner | description |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| 1      | john  | some text   |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| 2      | john  | some text   |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| 3      | john  | some text   |
+--------+-------+-------------+
| 4      | jack  | some text   |
+--------+-------+-------------+
```

Table 3: request

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| requestid | technician | title     | description |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 1         | john       | some text | ...         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 2         | sara       | some text | ...         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 3         | john       | some text | ...         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 4         | jack       | some text | ...         |
+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Now I need to SQL query for this result:

```
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| technician | count(worklogid) | count(taskid) | count(requestid) |
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| john       | 2                | 3             | 2                |
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| jack       | 1                | 1             | 1                |
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| jenifer    | 1                | 0             | 0                |
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
| sara       | 0                | 0             | 1                |
+------------+------------------+---------------+------------------+
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please include your current query.

Comment: I don't have any idea for this query

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Table 3: request

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I believe, database design has to be improved. No primary key or id is assigned to users.

Comment: @AT-2017 database design is not for me

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I need to SQL query to show result. Also my database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to just use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select techician, sum(is_workid), sum(is_taskid), sum(is_requestid)
from ((select technician, 1 as is_workid, 0 as is_taskid, 0 as is_requestid
       from worklog
      ) union all
      (select owner, 0, 1, 0
       from task
      ) union all
      (select technician, 0, 0, 1
       from request
      )
     ) t
group by technician;
```

In Postgres, you can also aggregate before joining:

```
select *
from (select technician, count(*) as num_workid
      from worklog
      group by technician
     ) w full join
     (select owner as technician, count(*) as num_task
      from task
      group by owner
     ) t
     using (technician) full join
     (select technician, count(*) as num_request
      from request
      group by technician
     ) w 
     using (technician);
```

With a `full join`, I find that `using` is simpler than `on` clauses.  But the name needs to be the same in all the tables.

Comment: I need to count of each record

Comment: Error me: Whenever a sub query is used in from clause, kindly use an alias name for the sub query @GordonLinoff

Comment: @EhsanAli . . . This has an alias, `t`.